# Talend on Windows will not connect to Hive

Tags: windows, hive, connection, talend

I am trying to make a standard DB connection from Talend to a Hive 2 install on a Cloudera platform. When I try to do so I get the error 'Function not supported on windows'

I am trying to determine if this error is accurate, and that Talend does not support connections to Hive on a Windows OS or is being triggered for a different reason.

I have searched through the Talend forums, and there is no straight answer to the question there. Could anyone shed some light on this query.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While connecting to hive from talend, it will give you two options.

1. Embedded Mode : Just passing parameter inside the linux shell with **hive**
   its automatically connect to the hive.
2. Standalone Mode : you can connect to any where other than cluster, like talend, pentaho and etc..
   even from the reporting tools we have to use standalone mode.

to connect the standalone mode we have to jdbc url with following format
**jdbc:hive://hostname:10000/default**

I hope you got the difference.

Thank you :)